# Kubernetes: /dev/vfio/0: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, kubernetes, containers, devops, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to deploy my kubernetes cluster but struck with **ContainerCreatingError** on one particular pod.

When I do describe on the pod, I found the following error.

```
spec: failed to generate spec: lstat /dev/vfio/0: no such file or directory
```

Followed this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/cbkg6j/devvfioxx_not_being_created/) (bound to vfio-pci module), but didn't work as expected. Any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe how you prepare the node and what's the pci module in your question.

Comment: I tried to tried to unbind and bind the driver but that didnt help. By pci module, I meant vfio-pci (VFIO - “Virtual Function I/O”)

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: I setup the cluster over mesos and kubernetes is in its most latest verison. I am setting it up on the baremetal.

Comment: What does it mean most latest verison? Which exactly version did you use?